# Error during CommcareHq installation

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu

I receive the following error when i try to compile commcareHq when i run manage.py validate

pastebin link : [pastebin.com/D5eYkcGS](http://pastebin.com/D5eYkcGS)

All dependencies have been installed and met

Im running ubuntu version 12.0.4

Comment: im installing commcarehq :>>https://github.com/dimagi/commcare-hq

Comment: Looks like your CouchDB client either isn't installed, or is not on your `PYTHONPATH`: `No module named couchlog`

Comment: i managed to fix the solution one needs to run git submodule update --init --recursive